# Width and Height of JPanel inside Container of JFrame is 0, why?

Tags: swing, height, width, jpanel, grid-layout

I am having a simple problem I guess, that u should know how to solve..
I am trying to do this:
I have a JFrame.
Then I create a JPanel and set his layout to GridLayout(5,5)
Finnaly I add this JPanel to the Container of my JFrame.

When I try to get the width of my panel it shouldnt give me 0 right?
I do this: System.out.println(mypanel.getSize().getWidth());   and it says that is zero :c
why ??
I wanna know the size so I can divide per 5 and know how much to paint for each label, this will be a grid of labels..
Thanks alot in advance...

```
    public janela(){

    window = new JFrame("teste");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(300,300);
    contentor = window.getContentPane();
    interior = new JPanel();
    interior.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
    contentor.add(interior);

    System.out.println(interior.getSize().getWidth());   //it says 0 ?!?! why??
     }
```

thanks alot in advance guys!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panels are sized based on their layout. specifically when they are shown and doLayout() is called for you. doLayout() figures out what the appropriate size for your panel is based on the contents of the panel, and the layout manager in force. Since your panel has nothing in it, the appropriate size is 0, 0.

If you will never have anything in the panel, and want to circumvent this (0, 0) size, you can override getPreferredSize() of the panel to return a size that you want the panel to respect for layout.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! But look I tryed to add before my labels to the panel, and then try to get the size.. but still zero.. 

look my code here mate: http://pastebin.com/FEtFnK9r

thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: doLayout is only called when the window is visible. Unless i missed it, make sure you call setVisible(true), before checking sizes.